# deploy spring boot application on tomcat, should I replace all my app's urls

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, deployment

I arrived to deploy my spring boot application on tomcat, I followed this site `https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/`

But I did changes to my html files:
my application name is : `GestionRetardApp` its version is '0.0.1'
before making changes in my html files, I have this file as example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="layout/layout">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
        <center>
            <form action="/searchByName">
                <table>
                    <tr>                        
                        <td><select name="nomprenom" class="form-control">
                                <th:block th:each="p : ${rhEmployeesList}">
                                    <option th:text="${p.nomPrenom}" th:value="${p.nomPrenom}"></option>
                                </th:block>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
            </form>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I find my self forced to change `<form action="/searchByName">` to

```
<form action="/GestionRetardApp-0.0.1/searchByName">
```

I did that for all the urls that I have!
Is there another way to keep my default code and don't make changes to my html files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.....
1. use `<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />`

2. Use a global javascript variable and append it with all network calls
3. pass the `baseUrl` as parameter to template. Then: `<a th:href="${baseUrl + '/my/uri?maybe=' + someParam}"`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your application as default in tomcat.

> Steps:
>
> - delete the ROOT directory
> - name your war file "ROOT.war" (capitals mandatory)
> - drop the ROOT.war file directly in the /webapps directory.

There are other ways, too please read [How do I make my web application be the Tomcat default application?](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F)

Comment: thankx @Sukhpa, but this solution will make my app the default Tomcat application, and what can I do in the case that I have many applications to deploy on tomcat?